# How to join two tables but not to repeat rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am facing one issue for getting data. I am new in Mysql. Firstly i will show my table structure

```
order_products
id  user_id product_id  product_name
1    1        10           Jacket1
2    1        10           Jacket2

order_products_sizes
id    order_product_id  size    qty
1          1             S      56
2          1             M      36
3          1             XL     36
4          1             2XL    56
5          2             S      32
6          2             M      28
7          2             XL     28
8          2             2XL    32
9          2             3XL    69

 My expected Output:-
product_name     S    M   XL  2XL  3XL
  JACKET1       56   36  36   56 
  JACKET2       32   28  28   32    69 

 for first row 3xl would be empty beacuse there is no size available in order_product_sizes
```

Actually i am using join but when i use join the rows are repeating because of joining two table that is actual behavior of joins.
I have tries so far:-

```
SELECT order_products.product_name,
CASE 
WHEN order_product_sizes.order_product_id = order_products.id AND 
order_product_sizes.size = 'L' THEN  order_product_sizes.qty    
END AS L
from order_products
join 
order_product_sizes
on order_products_sizes.order_product_id = order_products.id;
```

Comment: `Actually i am using join but when i use join the rows are repeating because of joining two table that is actual behavior of joins` => yes it is. Please describe us what you are trying to achieve and the logic behind it

Comment: @Simonare see my expected output

Comment: @Simonare  i want my sizes would firstly treat as column then the qty of sizes will come in one row not to repeat the rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below - using conditional aggregation

```
SELECT order_products.product_name,
max(CASE 
WHEN 
order_product_sizes.size = 'S' THEN  order_product_sizes.qty    
END) AS S,
max(CASE 
WHEN 
order_product_sizes.size = 'M' THEN  order_product_sizes.qty    
END) AS M,
max(CASE 
WHEN 
order_product_sizes.size = 'XL' THEN  order_product_sizes.qty    
END) AS XL,
max(CASE 
WHEN 
order_product_sizes.size = '2XL' THEN  order_product_sizes.qty    
END) AS '2XL',
max(CASE 
WHEN 
order_product_sizes.size = '3XL' THEN  order_product_sizes.qty    
END) AS '3XL'
from order_products join order_products_sizes
on order_products_sizes.order_product_id = order_products.id
group by order_products_sizes.order_product_id
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'from order_products join order_product_sizes
on order_products_sizes.order_prod' at line 22

Comment: An expression was expected. (near "from" at position 531)

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'from order_products join order_products_sizes
on order_products_sizes.order_pro' at line 22

Comment: yes its working but its showing only one record but it must come  two records :(

Comment: @kunal ,I've changed a bit - but it should provide you your expected result - if your's data's are ok

Comment: yeah its working now can you tell me how can i make sizes dyanmic means i future if add new size id 5XL i need to update query again to add 5XL condition

Comment: @kunal, what is your mysql version - you need to apply dynamic pivot - anyway if this answer helped u please mark it as accepted answer

Comment: yeah sure bro...Mysql version is 10.1.30-MariaDB can you help me for that thing if new size comes then it will automatically fetch

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185708/discussion-between-kunal-and-fa06).